# How to insert a stdlib C function in llvm using IRBuilder?

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I'm a beginner to llvm. What I want to achieve here is once a variable is declared then sanitize it to a random value. For example,

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define enable_init 1

static const int len = 10;

void print(int* x, int len);

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    int x[len];
    print(x, len);
    return 0;
}

void print(int* x, int len){
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
        printf("0x%08x \n",x[i]);
    }
}
```

After Instrumentation,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define enable_init 1

static const int len = 10;

void print(int* x, int len);
void forceInit(void *ptr, size_t size);

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    int x[len];
    forceInit(x, sizeof(int) * len);
    print(x, len);
    return 0;
}

void print(int* x, int len){
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
        printf("0x%08x \n",x[i]);
    }
}

void forceInit(void *ptr, size_t size){
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(size_t i=0;i<size;i++){
        unsigned char r = (unsigned char)(rand() % 255);
        memset(ptr+i,r,1);
    }
}
```

Here is a simple code I wrote for this:

```
void visitAllocaInst(AllocaInst &I) {
    IRBuilder<> IRB(I.getNextNode());
    Value *toVar = IRB.CreatePointerCast(&I, IRB.getInt8PtrTy());
    Value *deadbeef = IRB.getInt8(255);
    IRB.CreateMemSet(toVar, deadbeef, Len, I.getAlignment());
}
```

The current version can only assign variable to 0xFF. I found CreateMemSet function in the API of IRBuilder however I have no idea how to deal with rand().

Comment: You probably want to insert a call to a standard function. You should probably use its name.

Comment: tried it. The instrumented code doesn't link to runtime stdlib.

Comment: compilation and link are separate things. BTW, you should not call `srand(time(NULL))` more than once in the generated code ; that `srand(time(NULL))` should go into the `main` of the generated code

Comment: thank you. so how can I get everything linked if I inserted rand() in my opt pass?

Comment: At first, you could require your user to explicitly call `srand(time(NULL))` in his `main`; and you could generate calls to `rand` in your instrumentation. How to do that is a different question.